# Visual Studio Task list - tree view

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to view the tasks in the task list in a tree structure according to the project and maybe even classes? Only sorting by project without being able to filter by the class structure is not useful if I want to ensure that I did not forget anything in the feature I'm working on but I do not intend to see TODOs in other parts of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the contents of the Task list -> Grouping. Multiple options can be selected. The order of selection does matter.